# SVG Pie Chart Breaks on Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery, css, svg

My inline SVG animated pie chart works fine on Chrome, Firefox, and Safari, but it breaks in Internet Explorer. The SVG stretches vertically and creates a duplicate background element on the SVG instead of just the . I've tried the preserveAspectRatio tag but that didn't seem to work. Snippet below:

```js
var chart = '<svg viewBox="0 0 32 32"><circle class="circle" r="16" cx="16" cy="16" style="stroke-dasharray: 0 100" /></svg>';
$('.pie__container--chart').html(chart);
var chart = $('.pie__container--chart circle');
    
setTimeout(function () { 
  chart.css('stroke-dasharray',  30 + ' 100');
  $('.pie__container--percent').css('opacity', '1');
}, 500);
  
jQuery('button').mouseover(function() {
  num = $(this).attr('data-val');
  $('.pie__container--percent').text(num + '%').addClass('animated');
  setTimeout(function () { 
    $('.pie__container--percent').removeClass('animated');
  }, 500);
  chart.css('stroke-dasharray',  num + ' 100');
  $('button').not(this).removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%; 
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 1em;
  font-family: 'Proxima Nova', 'Helvetica', sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  background: #163C4A;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #316F81, #163C4A) !important;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

button {
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: .5em 1em;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #ffffff;
  transition: all .2s ease;
  
}

button.active {
  background-color: #F2AE1C;
  border-color: #F2AE1C;
}

button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

@keyframes fillup {
  from { stroke-dasharray: 0 100; }
}

.pie__container--chart svg {
  width: 100%; 
  height: 100%;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.pie__container--chart circle {
  fill: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  stroke: #F2AE1C;
  stroke-width: 32;
  stroke-dasharray: 0 100; 
  transition: stroke-dasharray .5s ease;
}

.pie__container--chart {
  margin-bottom: 2em;
}

.pie__container {
  position: relative;
}

.pie__container--percent {
  position:absolute;
  right:18%;
  top:22%;
  font-size: 32px;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-weight: 600;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 1s ease;
}

@keyframes animated {
  from {opacity: .25;}
  to {opacity: 1;}
}

.pie__container--percent.animated {
  animation: animated 1s ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pie">
  <div class="pie__container">
    <div class="pie__container--chart"></div>
    <div class="pie__container--percent">30%</div>
  </div>
  <button class="active" data-val="59">2018</button>
  <button data-val="63">2017</button>
  <button data-val="25">2016</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

IE will display it fine if you set `stroke-width: 31.95` on `.pie__container--chart circle`.

Also I've fixed the issue when 100% does not fill the full circle:

```js
var chart = '<svg viewBox="0 0 32 32"><circle class="circle" r="16" cx="16" cy="16" style="stroke-dasharray: 0 100" /></svg>';
$('.pie__container--chart').html(chart);
var chart = $('.pie__container--chart circle');
    
setTimeout(function () { 
  chart.css('stroke-dasharray',  50 + ' 100');
  $('.pie__container--percent').css('opacity', '1');
}, 500);
  
jQuery('button').mouseover(function() {
  num = $(this).attr('data-val');
  $('.pie__container--percent').text(num + '%').addClass('animated');
  setTimeout(function () { 
    $('.pie__container--percent').removeClass('animated');
  }, 500);
  chart.css('stroke-dasharray', +num/180 + +num + ' 100');
  $('button').not(this).removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%; 
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 1em;
  font-family: 'Proxima Nova', 'Helvetica', sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  background: #163C4A;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #316F81, #163C4A) !important;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

button {
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: .5em 1em;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #ffffff;
  transition: all .2s ease;
  
}

button.active {
  background-color: #F2AE1C;
  border-color: #F2AE1C;
}

button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

@keyframes fillup {
  from { stroke-dasharray: 0 100; }
}

.pie__container--chart svg {
  width: 100%; 
  height: 100%;
  transform: rotateZ(-90deg);
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.pie__container--chart circle {
  fill: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  stroke: #F2AE1C;
  stroke-width: 31.95;
  stroke-dasharray: 0 100; 
  transition: stroke-dasharray .5s ease;
}

.pie__container--chart {
  margin-bottom: 2em;
}

.pie__container {
  position: relative;
}

.pie__container--percent {
  position:absolute;
  right:18%;
  top:22%;
  font-size: 32px;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-weight: 600;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 1s ease;
}

@keyframes animated {
  from {opacity: .25;}
  to {opacity: 1;}
}

.pie__container--percent.animated {
  animation: animated 1s ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pie">
  <div class="pie__container">
    <div class="pie__container--chart"></div>
    <div class="pie__container--percent">50%</div>
  </div>
  <button data-val="100">2019</button>
  <button class="active" data-val="50">2018</button>
  <button data-val="75">2017</button>
  <button data-val="25">2016</button>
</div>
```